# How to get access to 'r_1st_connections' & 'r_member_social' scopes for Linkedin API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am not able to fetch the list of connections, posts and reactions via linkedIn API. After going through the documentation, I came to know that two permissions are missing that is 'r_1st_connections' & 'r_member_social'. Don't know how to grant that to my app.

Can someone confirm how to get all my connections, posts and reactions from Linkedin via API.

I created the app and granted access below:

- Sign in with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect
- Share on LinkedIn
- Advertising API

I am referring to the Linkedin API documentation links below for get connections:

URL 1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/connections-api?context=linkedin%2Fcompliance%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-unversioned&preserve-view=true#total-number-of-connections
**error**
"message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-viewer /connections",

as per this message I need to get access for 'r_1st_connections' scope for fetching the list of user connections. I am not able to find where to enable this.
I searched and found that its closed, is there any other way i can handle it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

URL 2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/contacts-api
This API is also not working and giving me following error
url: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/contactExporterTasks

**error:**
"message": "Resource contactExporterTasks does not exist"